# Renaming App in App Store Only

Tags: app-store

I have an app that is already approved by Apple and is on sale in the App Store.  I want to add a word to the name of my app on the app store only. I do not want to change the name of my app as it appears on the actual device.  Do I have to change anything in my actual project other than the version number in order to accomplish this?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The name that appears in the App store is independent of the name that appears under the icon of an app (which is set as the app's Bundle Display Name in it's plist).  You can change the name to be used by the App store when submitting an update in iTunes Connect.  The update has to be approved by Apple before the updated app and name appear in the App store.